# How do I know if I started New Game+?

Tags: fiz

I finished *Fiz* and started a new game from the menu, but nothing seems different. There's also no option to speed up the game. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you see Cyrus Uprum again, then you did not start New Game+.

When you start a New Game+, the intro cutscene is skipped, as well as the tutorial. You jump straight into Y1 M1 W1 with your previous staff, equipment, and ingredients (but not recipes). You also immediately have access to both Your Bodega and Eddy's Bodega.